# Positioning an element inside the Canvas by its center (instead of the top left corner) using only XAML in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, centering

The common question about positioning an element inside a `Canvas` is "How to position the center of element (instead of the top left corner)".

- [WPF: Resizing a circle, keeping the center point instead of TopLeft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423834/wpf-resizing-a-circle-keeping-the-center-point-instead-of-topleft)
- [WPF Center Ellipse at X, Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422897/wpf-center-ellipse-at-x-y)
- [WPF element positioning on a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682111/wpf-element-positioning-on-a-canvas)

Several solutions are presented, but they all have drawbacks.

The easiest solution is to accommodate the element size during while setting the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties programmatically. This works, but only once. This solution doesn't support bindings and it will break when the element size is changed. You also cannot set the `Canvas.Left` or `Canvas.Top` using

Another set of solutions involve translate transformations utilizing either `RenderTransform` or `Margin`. These solutions require binding some property to the `-0.5 * Width` or `-0.5 * Height`. Such binding requires creating a custom `ValueConverter` and is impossible to create using only XAML.

**So, is there a simple way to position an element inside canvas so that its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` correspond to the element's center and both size and position properties can be bound to some other properties?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*XAML and bindings seem very powerful, but sometimes there are simple problems that require very complex solutions. In my bindings library creating such binding would be as easy as writing `element.Center = position` or `element.TopLeft = position - element.Size / 2`, but don't let me get carried away.*

I've found a very simple solution which uses only XAML and supports binding both size and position properties of the element. It seems that when the WPF control with alignment set too `Stretch` or `Center` is placed inside the canvas, the element "gravitates" towards centering as the `(Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top)` point (the state that we desire), but is stopped by the "angle plate" placed at the same `(Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top)` point. How do I know about this "gravitation"? It's evident when you ease the block by setting the `Margin` of the element to a negative value. Setting the negative margin allows the element to move towards its center goal. The element moves until the `Margin` reaches `(-Height / 2, -Width / 2)` so that the element becomes perfectly centered at the `(Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top)` point. Further changes don't cause any movement since the element is already perfectly positioned.

**Solution: set `Margin="-1000000"`.**

So in the following code the ellipses are both centered at the (200, 200) point. The first ellipse has `Left` and `Top` properties corresponding to the ellipse center allowing to easily bind them with some other objects' properties.

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Red" Margin="-100000" />
    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="150" Opacity="0.5" Fill="Blue" />
</Canvas>
```

The bad thing is this solution only work in WPF. Silverlight and WinRT don't have the described behavior.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler, at least for Shapes, would be to use a Path with an appropriate Geometry:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting the canvas into the bottom-right cell of a 2x2 grid. That makes the 0,0 coordinate the center of the grid, and then you can do all your drawing relative to that.

Comment: Could you post your xaml?

Comment: The question is not asking how to place items with respect to the center of the canvas; the question is asking how to place items in a canvas (using `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`) ***with respect to the center of the items.***

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me [Center text at a given point on a WPF Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778294/center-text-at-a-given-point-on-a-wpf-canvas).  He uses a MultiBinding and a custom Converter to adjust the margin on his element.  Brilliant!

Comment: I've mentioned such solutions. As I've said, I wanted a fully-declarative XAML-only solution.