# Positioning an element inside the Canvas by its center (instead of the top left corner) using only XAML in Silverlight/WinRT

Tags: silverlight, xaml, canvas, windows-runtime, centering

The common question about positioning an element inside a `Canvas` is "How to position the center of element (instead of the top left corner)".

- [WPF: Resizing a circle, keeping the center point instead of TopLeft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423834/wpf-resizing-a-circle-keeping-the-center-point-instead-of-topleft)
- [WPF Center Ellipse at X, Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422897/wpf-center-ellipse-at-x-y)
- [WPF element positioning on a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682111/wpf-element-positioning-on-a-canvas)

Several solutions are presented, but they all have drawbacks.

**Is there a simple (XAML-only) method to position an element inside canvas so that its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` correspond to the element's center AND both size and position properties can be bound to some other properties?**

I've found a very easy way to do this in WPF (just set `Margin="-1000000"` [Positioning an element inside the Canvas by its center (instead of the top left corner) using only XAML in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219321/wpf-positioning-an-element-by-its-center-instead-of-the-top-left-corner-insid/13219322#13219322)), but it doesn't work for Silverlight/WinRT. The only other method that I know requires creating `ValueConverter` to perform the `x *= -0.5` calculation (which is not XAML-only).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning an element inside the Canvas by its center (instead of the top left corner) using only XAML in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219321/positioning-an-element-inside-the-canvas-by-its-center-instead-of-the-top-left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not pretty, here's an example of using nested `RenderTransform`s with different origins to offset the position of the object to make it so that it's centered:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UrlTest.Center"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ContentControl Canvas.Top="100" Content="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Center, StringFormat=Width \{0\}}"/>
        <ContentControl Canvas.Top="120" Content="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=Center, StringFormat=Height \{0\}}"/>
        <Grid x:Name="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="-.5,-.5" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="25">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="-1"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="-.25,-.25">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="-1"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Ellipse Width="80" Height="50" Fill="Aquamarine"/>
                <ContentControl FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Center</ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

The inner `Grid`s are for creating the transforms, while the outer `Canvas` is there to make sure the `Grid` inside of it sets its size to that of the content inside of it.

Comment: Pretty ingenious! I've tried to solve the system of several transformation equations to come to a solution like this, but failed. These double transform does the deal nicely. P.S. The RenderTransformOrigin values can also be `0,0`; `0.25,0.25` or `-0.25,-0.25`; `0,0`. They just need to satisfy the `Internal - External = 1/4` equation.